# How to replace any unnecessary text between two characters in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

On my WordPress site, I want to remove all the text between two forward slashes `/unnecessary text/` in one of the tables in the database.

Table: `wp_mtouchquiz_answer`

Column: `answer`

However, I only want to remove the text between 2 slashes. Any text before or after two slashes should remain.

I would be grateful if you could help.

Comment: Does your column value contains strictly two slashes?

Comment: yes, is there at most one instance of the two slashes in any given value?  or could there be more e.g. "foo /remove me/ bar /remove me too/ baz"

Comment: Also - does the amount of slashes per value is always even?

Comment: @Akina, yes, the column value contains strictly two slashes and the number of slashes per value is always even.

Comment: @ysth, there is only one instance in each value.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply:

```
update wp_mtouchquiz_answer set answer=regexp_replace(answer, '/.*/', '')
```

or if you want the slashes kept,

```
update wp_mtouchquiz_answer set answer=regexp_replace(answer, '/.*/', '//')
```

This does require mysql 8 or mariadb.  For old versions, you would do:

```
update wp_mtouchquiz_answer
set answer=concat(substring_index(answer, '/', 1), substring_index(answer, '/', -1))
where answer like '%/%/%';
```